# Configuring many OAuth2 grant types in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application that is using two OAuth2 Grant Types:

- client_credentials
- List item

authorization code

Actually I did'nt find an example of a Spring Security configuration for configuring both grant_types.

What I am actually doing is silly:

```
public class CustomTokenServices implements ResourceServerTokenServices {
...
    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessToken) {
        OAuth2Authentication authenticationAsUserInfo = null;

        try {
            authenticationAsUserInfo = loadAuthenticationAsUserInfo(accessToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (authenticationAsUserInfo == null) {
            return loadAuthenticationAsRemote(accessToken);
        }
        return authenticationAsUserInfo;
    }
...
}
```

It is an if-else solution which is not actually convenient solution :(

Comment: Please specify exact versions, as the Spring Security OAuth2 support is under an overhaul. Also, to clarify, you're trying to write a custom token-services for a resource server? Why are you treating some token authority as local and some as remote instead of always fetching from remote?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2 + Spring Security 5.. my application is using OKTA for OAuth2, this is why it is requesting OKTA for loading Authentication..